# What port does OpenLink ODBC Driver use?

Tags: firewall, port, tcp, odbc, drivers

I use Avaya Reporting Services and OpenLink ODBC Drivers for db connection. I know that it uses port 5000 for handshaking but after that I believe it uses an random port for communication. I want to deploy my application and it will communicate with the client's system in their datacenter. They are asking what ports should they open on their firewalls. I can't obviously give them a range above 50,000 that I know OpenLink ODBC Drivers use. Can someone tell me what port should I tell my client to open?

Answer (score 1):

Does the server that will be communicating to your client with the OpenLink ODBC driver have a static IP? If you can't nail down a specific port, you might be able to solve it by having your client allow a range of ports only from your IP address. It's still a range, but significantly more secure than opening up a range to all IPs.

Answer (score 0):

You indicate the intention to deploy your own application, thus can you confirm if the OpenLink ODBC Driver in use was acquired from OpenLink Software directly or is this the OEM'ed OpenLink ODBC Driver shipped with the Avaya product ? I ask as the latter is only licensed for use with the Avaya CMS applications and not for any other applications, which would require the purchase of a separate ODBC Driver license from OpenLink Software ...

Best Regards
Hugh Williams
OpenLink Software

Answer (score 0):

The OpenLink (my employer) Multi-Tier Generic Client initiates connections with a call to the server-side OpenLink Request Broker (`oplrqb`), which listens on port 5000 by default.

The Request Broker responds to the Client with information about the Database Agent which will handle that connection, including the Agent's service port.  By default, the Agent's service port is dynamically assigned by its host OS, and may be any from 5000-60000.

The Broker's listen port, and the port range for Agents, are configurable, in the server-side Broker Rulebook (`oplrqb.ini`).

[Full documentation](http://docs.openlinksw.com/mt/) is accessible on the web, as are the [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), and [Case System](http://support.openlinksw.com:8889/opie/kbase/employees/cases/casesearch.vsp).